# Unmarshall deep nested array in golang

Tags: go, arraylist, unmarshalling

I am trying to iterate over the "Inner" elements in "List", but only the last "Inner - type" is recovered, ie, "c1":

```
jsonData := []byte(`{
"List": [{
    "Inner":{"type":"a1"},      
    "Inner":{"type":"b1"},
    "Inner":{"type":"c1"}
}]}`)

type Test struct {
  List []struct {
    Inner struct {
      Type string `json:"type"` 
    } `json:"Inner"`
  } `json:"List"`
}

var test Test
json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &test)

fmt.Println(test.List[0].Inner.Type)
```

So, Is there any way to print all elements in "List" ?

Answer (score 2):

you might need to decide on a type for the objects coming inside the []List object, and implement the JSONUnmarshaller interface with a custom logic as follows to achieve this.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

type Inner struct{
    Type string `json:"type"`
}

type List []Inner

type Test struct {
    List [] List `json:"List"`
}

func main() {
    jsonData := []byte(`{
"List": [{
    "Inner":{"type":"a1"},      
    "Inner":{"type":"b1"},
    "Inner":{"type":"c1"}
}]}`)

    var test Test
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &test)
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    for _,v := range test.List[0]{
        fmt.Println(v.Type)
    }
}

func (l *List) UnmarshalJSON(bytes []byte) error {
    out := make(List,0)
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`"Inner":{.*}`)
    objects := re.FindAll(bytes,-1)
    for _,v := range objects{
        inner := Inner{}
        s := strings.TrimLeft(string(v),`"Inner":`)
        err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s),&inner)
        if err != nil{
            return err
        }
        out = append(out,inner)
    }
    *l = out
    return nil
}
```

output:

```
a1
b1
c1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple identical keys on the same object in JSON:

```js
console.log(JSON.parse(`{
    "Inner":{"type":"a1"},      
    "Inner":{"type":"b1"},
    "Inner":{"type":"c1"}
}`))
```

so without writing a custom unmarshaller, no.

Comment: From the [JSON spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159) you *can* have duplicate keys - however... `When the names within an object are not unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is unpredictable.  Many implementations report the last name/value pair only.  Other implementations report an error or fail to parse the object, and some implementations report all of the name/value pairs, including duplicates.`